# Is this considered Privilege Escalation?

Tags: access-control, privilege-escalation

Suppose I have an Admin account and a normal user account. There is some functionality that is only accessible to the admin only, like promoting other users. In this scenario, I captured a request from the admin when the admin is promoting other users and I changed admin cookie or token with the normal user and that action is performed using normal user cookie.

Is this considered "privilege escalation"?

I asked this because if admin-accessible functionality is performed using a normal user cookie successfully so in order to exploit this scenario normal users only needed to find an endpoint for that functionality.

Comment: " I changed admin cookie or token with the normal user " -- how did you do this? While logged in as admin? We need a little more detail here.

Comment: @schroeder yes login with admin and perform some feature which is only accessible to admin and on that request change cookie or token with normal user

Comment: So, no, that's not necessarily "escalation". That's potentially a failed "de-escalation". I think your test is faulty.

Comment: If a privileged action can be carried out using a non-admin cookie, then its not privilege escalation. It is still a very serious security flaw - authorization is not being enforced.

Comment: @symcbean but it appears from the comments that they logged in as an admin, captured a user cookie, passed the user cookie while still logged in as admin. The test assumes that the cookie is the authorisation.

Comment: Who they logged in as initially is irrelevant - if the only credentials they provided in this HTTP request was the session token for a non-privileged user then that demonstrates that the application is not checking for authorization.

Comment: @symcbean but I'm saying that if the cookie is the only means of authentication, then you might be correct. But we don't know how the system works. The fact that a user cookie was passed might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:** You are testing a web application and have credentials for both admin and regular user.  You tried an admin-only operation with the session cookie of a non-admin.

If it went through, then yes, that is a [Vertical Privilege Escalation](https://portswigger.net/web-security/access-control).  You are correct that a normal user only needs to find the right endpoint to carry out the escalation and endpoint URLs cannot be considered secret in this case.

Comment: can bug bounty programs give rewards for finding this bug?

Comment: absolutely they can.

Comment: A clarification: I would _not_ classify this as **privilege escalation** but rather as a flaw in **access control** a.k.a. **authorization**. Privilege escalation would be if e.g. a user could modify their own access token to turn it from User to Admin, or otherwise trick the service into thinking the user is more privileged than they are. Whereas here, the developer has apparently just plain failed to restrict the API to only Admins, even though they clearly intend it to be admin-only.